# Harmonizing two different monitor setups in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, laptop, microsoft-outlook, multiple-monitors

I have a work-provided laptop that I work from home with two days a week. My workplace provides two monitors, keyboard, mouse and docking station, so I just plug in the USB-C and it works. One of the monitors is marked as the "main" display for Windows (not the laptop screen, because otherwise the dock forgets the monitors when I restart the PC). At home, I have one big monitor that I own, and that is marked or becomes the "main" screen for Windows. No docking station for home, but I use a hub with keyboard and mouse plugged in to it. I shut down the PC when moving it.

Programs move to different displays when I go home or to work, so I have to move things around every time. The worst offender is **Outlook**, which I want to glue to the Laptop screen, because I don't use the laptop screen for anything else. Is there a way to force Outlook to always open there? I have resized the window so it just fits the screen, but it still moves around when I change locations. Win-Shift-Arrows is very helpful to move it to the correct display, but doesn't put it in the right spot.

Doesn't Windows support a Home and Workplace setup, the way some cars have a "husband and wife" pair of settings for the driver's seat and mirror positions? Seems like a good idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no relevant setting in Outlook to control which monitor it opens automatically. However, you can set it in Windows to tick the primary monitor and then Outlook will open on the specific monitor.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I set the laptop screen as the "Main Display" in Windows. Now Outlook opens there. That's one less thing I have to move every time.

Possibly the issue we had in the past of the docking station losing attached monitors unless one was marked the Main Display has been fixed (if not, I'll have to switch back because I need screens more than I need convenience).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).